# How to use create and design an interface that contains two different forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, multiple-forms

I am crating a program (in c#, using visual studios 2010) that will have 3 different windows. each of them needs to be accessible from one another (by the toolstrip/menustrip) and they refer to the same information (Same variables, databases ect...
My question, is what is the best way to crate and design these different interfaces?
I can think of two ways, but both of them have some disadvanteges.

The first way I thought of is to make a "Hide/show" void that will hide turn the visible of all of the components in the first Area to false, and will Turn all the wanted components Visible to true.

the problem, is that it's stupid and messy.

the second way I thought of - is using a second form.

Disadvanteges - all the variable transfer is quite a mess, and mainly - I don't want different forms to pop up. I want it all under one program.

I guess there is an efficient and smarter way to do this.
I hope I was clear enough in this matter.

Thank you,

Barak.

Comment: No, It doesent have to be (The user doesen't need to use more than one of the 'forms' at once).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a master form (like master page in asp.net) and inherit all three forms from this master form.